# биндинг handler'а

Tags: angularjs

Есть проблема:
в компоненте подписался на событие, 
при открытии модала надо от него отписаться,
(модал открывается из другого компонента).

Что делаю:
прокидываю handler(`bindings: {
        myHandler: '&'
    },`) в тот компонент, где открывается модал и там в $mdDialog.show

```
onComplete: function(){

                angular.element(document.body).off('keyup', ctrl.myHandler);
            }
```

и не работает такая схема, после биндинга handler консолится как
`h()
​
length: 1
​
name: ""
​
prototype: Object { … }
​
<prototype>: function ()`
 т.е.  имя теряется, видимо, поэтому и не работает 
может кто знает как решить?

Comment: добавь рабочий пример кода, сейчас совсем непонятно что ты делаешь, что у тебя выходит и что ты ожидал увидеть.

Comment: код очень сложно добавить, проект огромный , но я попробую как-то упростить

Comment: Не нужен весь проект. нуден [mcve] настолько минимальный на сколько это возможно

Comment: Вопрос снимается, т.к. правильней, всё-таки, написать сервис для этого и не прокидывать хэндлеры каждый раз для отписки от событий, спасибо. Как правильно закрыть вопрос?

Answer (score 0):

Нашлось решение, надо прокидывать не handler, а функцию в которой происходит отписка от события, вместо этого

`onComplete: function(){
                angular.element(document.body).off('keyup', ctrl.myHandler);
            }`
будет так

```
onComplete: function(){
                ctrl.eventListenerOff();
            }
```

а в первом компоненте

```
ctrl.eventListenerOff = function(){
            angular.element(document.body).off('keyup', ctrl.myHandler);
        };
```